# Submit Form with Data Model and Get JSON Reply

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor

I have a form in a razor view that is defined like:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "CT0, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "rForm" }))
```

I have a method in CT0 called submit, that accepts a model:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Submit(CTModel ctmodel)
```

When I submit the form like this, it hits the function with the correct model, but I can't get the JSON reposonse:

```
var form = document.getElementById('rForm');
form.submit();
```

I've tried ajax, but it does not submit to the controller, or error, or success. It seemingly does nothing:

```
         $("#rForm").submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

            var form = $(this);
            var url = form.attr('action');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data); // show response from the php script.
                }
            });


        });
```

I tried jquery, but it never hits the submit function in the controller or error out. It seems to do nothing:

```
        $(function () {
            $('form[name=rForm]').submit(function () {
                $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (json) {
                    alert(json);
                }, 'json');
                return false;
            });
        });
```

So any idea on how I submit the form, with the model, and get a response?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
        var form = $("#rForm");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/CT0/Submit",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                showModal("Error Getting Address: " + data.message);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                showModal("Error Getting Address: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        })
```